# Django - Run collectstatic to collect static files but collect all the files in the project directory instead

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-storage, zappa

I am trying to run collectstatic command to collect all of the my static files from the subdirectories of apps and deployed them to my Amazon S3 buckets.
I tried to use Zappa following the steps as found in this link: https://romandc.com/zappa-django-guide/walk_static/

After running the command `python /manage.py collectstatic`, all of the files in my project directory get copied into the static folder. Plus, it is not deployed into the S3 bucket.

Here is my code:

```html
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static"),
]
if os.environ.get("collectstatic")=='True':
    # STATICFILES_DIRS += 'static',

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test')

#STATIC FILE SETTNGS FOR S3
#Used when we seperate css and js into a static folder
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.S3Storage"

if os.environ.get('stage'):
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage"
    AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC = 'static-myapp-'+ os.environ.get('stage')
    # These next two lines will serve the static files directly from the s3 bucket
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC
    STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS+=BASE_DIR,

# AWS BUCKET FOR UPLOADED FILES
AWS_S3_UPLOAD_BUCKET = "myapp-uploads"
```

Can anyone point out what I did wrong please? Thank you!

Comment: All files being copied must mean that `STATICFILES_DIRS+=BASE_DIR` is executed. This line is telling django to copy everything from the `BASE_DIR` into STATIC_ROOT. Check that you are loading your environment variables correctly because it seems `if os.environ.get('stage'):` is evaluating to `False`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!
Also, just a quick question. My solution is to set up os.environ['stage'] inside the setting file in Django. Is that a bad practice? If so, what is a better alternative?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's bad practice per se. The drawback would be that every time you wanted to switch between local static storage and S3 you would have to manually remove/replace that code. Could lead to the same situation again if you comment it out and forget about it when deploying.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you so much!